# Prove that $A^HB^H=(BA)^H$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove this statement where A and B are matrices and H the Hermitian. Ok, Here is a proof from MathWorld:

$$\overline{((ab)^T)_{ij}}=\overline{(b^Ta^T)_{ij}}=\overline{{b^T_{ik}}a^T_{kj}}=(b^Ha^H)_{ij}$$

With one or two steps disregarded.

I understand the proof but I fail to see how the coordinate k pops up and disappears. Could you make a brief explanation or if there are otherways to prove this, could you explain them (seems this is  the only straightforward way, though) :

$A^HB^H=(BA)^H$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is written in [Einstein sum convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), meaning that there is an implicit sum over the index $k$ that appears twice. With the regular matrix multiplication (row times column) we have for $A = a_{ij}$ and $B=b_{ij}$
$$ (A\cdot B)_{ij} = \sum_k a_{ik} b_{kj} $$